# How to dynamically filter jTable from textfield in netbeans from SQLite?

Tags: java, swing, sqlite, netbeans-8

I'm very new to this to please excuse my lack of knowledge.

I am making a Document manager database with SQLite and I am trying to get my `JTextField` KeyReleased search to update dynamically and filter my `JTable` as I type to show all matching results.

I am told that the `JTable` already has functionality to do filtering without additional queries but all I was able to find was the `autoCreateRowSorter` which is not what I'm trying to do.

Here is my initial code for the table connection and my update table method.

```
import com.sun.glass.events.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.Date;

public class Employee_info extends javax.swing.JFrame {
Connection conn=null;
ResultSet rs =null;
PreparedStatement pst=null;

/**
 * Creates new form Employee_info
 */
public Employee_info() {
    initComponents();
    conn=javaconnect.ConnecrDb();
    Update_table();
    Fillcombo();
}

private void Update_table(){

try{
String sql ="select * from Documents";
pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
rs=pst.executeQuery();
table_documents.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
table_documents.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(50);
table_documents.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(1);
table_documents.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(300);
table_documents.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(1);
table_documents.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(150);
}
catch (Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

} finally {   
try{
 rs.close();
 pst.close();
 //conn.close();
}       
catch (Exception e) {
                }  
}
}
```

Here is my `JTextfild event` (obvious I know).

```
private void txt_filterKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:

}
```

I understand that my code is crude and basic so apologies.

I just don't know where to start with this so all and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by reading the section from the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for a working example that does exactly what you want.

I suggest you bookmark the table of contents so you have a quick reference to basic Swing features.

Also method names should NOT start with an upper case character or contain an "_" in the name. Follow Java conventions which a used by the Java API.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and I have read that already but have been struggling to implement the filter into my code. The main part i don't understand is the TableFilterDemo.java requires SpringUtilities.java . Thank you for your reminder on naming methods which I did remember but only after I had already named lots of methods this way.

Comment: @slinky62, `requires SpringUtilities.java` - the code is included with the tutorial. However, that class is only used for the layout of components and is irrelevant for the filtering logic so don't even worry about it and just concentrate on the filtering logic and how the filter is invoked when text is changed in the text field.

Comment: Hi. Just to update.. I managed to work it out by copying and amending my Update_Table method string to.. String sql = "SELECT * FROM Documents WHERE Title LIKE '" + title_filter.getText() + "%'"; which I used in my keyReleased method. Didn't use the tableRowSorter in the end as this did exactly what I wanted. Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: @slinky62, `You can lead a horse to water but you can't force the horse to drink`. Why not learn to use the filtering properly? Again you have a working example to learn from!!! Invoking an SQL statement every time is not very efficient.

Comment: I should have been more clear.... I am still looking at implementing the tableRowSorter for any final build but all I needed was a working model for my presentation. This program is purely for proof of concept presentation. Your advise has helped tremendously for the future build so thanks again.